# Weblogic server window exit when start BI Publisher

Tags: oracle, weblogic, reporting, business-intelligence, bi-publisher

I have installed Oracle BI Publisher trail edition, when i click to Start BI Publisher to start server, command window appear and exit after 10 seconds. when i click again to Start BI Publisher, command window exit after 4 seconds. may be some errors are coming in sever window.

please advice.

Comment: Check log file for messages

Comment: I have checked here:
C:\Program Files\Oracle\BI Publisher Trial Edition\bip\server\wls\logs\wlst_20130407155608.log 

 com.oracle.cie.domain.ValidateException: Property "ConfirmUserPassword" of JDBCConnectionPool "bip_datasource" is invalid.
The property value is required.
 at com.oracle.cie.domain.aspect.XBeanConfigAspect.selfValidate(XBeanConfigAspect.java:558)
.
..
...
com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptExecutor - The "JDBC" configuration in your domain is invalid. Try to resolve the issue by reviewing your script. The wizard will continue, but you may want to start the server in the domain

Comment: So... did you look at the JDBC configuration? Is there a problem with your config files under <domain>/config/jdbc ?

Comment: there are two xml files in this path:
C:\Program Files\Oracle\BI Publisher Trial Edition\bip\server\domains\bipdomain\config\jdbc:
bip_datasource-jdbc.xml,
bipdemo-jdbc.xml

please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Go to weblogic console,

```
 http://mycomputer:7001/console/
```

in the left hand menu select `Services|JDBC|Datasources`

Select the bip_datasource

Select the Monitoring|Testing tab

Click the radio button and 'Test Data Source'

As logfile suggest the is probably an error in the value ConfirmUserPassword

Configuration|Connection pool

And re-enter "Password" and "Confirm password" fields.

Test Datasource again.

For more info see:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21043_01/bi.1111/e13880/T526682T526687.htm

Comment: I have installed Oracle BI Publisher Desktop and Oracle BI Publisher trail edition, now when i click to Start BI Publisher to start server, server window appear and exit after 10 seconds. i am not able to do anything.

Comment: You need to access Weblogic Server Admin console see edits in answer

Comment: Hi Sir,

when i trying to run the console under C:\Program Files\Oracle\BI Publisher Trial Edition\bip\configureBIP (Windows batch file). It asks:
Enter a userid for the Administrator user: Administrator (my userid)
password: Administrator1 (my password)
confirm password=  Administrator1 (my password)

Comment: it shows: ------Your environment has been set.------------------
Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
WARNING - Unable to create log file <C:\Program Files\Oracle\BI Publisher Trial
Edition\bip\server\wls\modules/../logs/wlst_20130413162947.log>: java.io.IOExcep
tion: Access is denied

Comment: Problem invoking WLST - java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\PROGRA~1\Oracle\BIPUBL
~2\bip\bipdomain_script.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
Could Not Find C:\PROGRA~1\Oracle\BIPUBL~2\bip\bipdomain_script.txt
The user:Administrator already exists.
C:\PROGRA~1\Oracle\BIPUBL~2\bip\server\domains\bipdomain\security\DefaultAuthent
icatorInit.ldift
Access is denied.
--------------------show some errors and exit

Comment: I have search this file: bipdomain_script.txt. this file is exist under C:\Program Files\Oracle\BI Publisher Trial Edition\bip\install\bipdomain_script.

Comment: Hi Sir,
I have re install Oracle BI Publisher trail edition. After complete the installation, server was running fine and i did login with Administrator user. after stop the server when i start the server again using: C:\Program Files\Oracle\BI Publisher Trial Edition\bip\win\runConfigureBIP. i fill userid and password. when it Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST), it is unable to create a log file then it give a IO exception and automatically shutdown. Is there any need to set any path in environment variables ? please advice. Thanks.